# ASP.Net MVC - Json data for Google Charts

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

Newbie to Google Charts, I am trying to create a Google Chart, controller returns JSON data like

```
{"data":[["In Progress","10"],["Completed","20"],["Deleted","5"],["Overdue","8"]]}
```

But data required for Google chart should be like

```
[["In Progress",10],["Completed",20],["Deleted","5"],["Overdue",8]]
```

I have following JS function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("TaskStatus", "Graph")',
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {                   
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

                var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dt.addColumn('string', 'Tasks');
                dt.addColumn('number', 'Count');

                $.each(arrJson, function (i, obj) {
                    $.each(obj, function (i, o) {
                        console.log(o[1]);                            
                        dt.addRow(o[0],parseInt(o[1])); // here I get error of datatype for "Count" column
                    })                                              
                })
                chartData = dt;
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
                console.log(err);
            }
        }).done(function () {
            drawChart();
        })
    })

function drawChart()
{           
var options = {
                width: '500px',
                title: "Task Status",
                pointSize: 20,
                chartArea:{width:"100%",height:"100px"}
            };
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        pieChart.draw(chartData, options);
}
```

**Controller returns**

```
List<object> temp = new List<object>();
            temp.Add(new[] { "In Progress", "10" });
            temp.Add(new[] { "Completed", "20" });
            temp.Add(new[] { "Deleted", "5" });
            temp.Add(new[] { "Overdue", "8" });

            return Json(new { data = temp });
```

Please advice how to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `JSON.stringify` function in your AJAX success callback as this will transform the object you got from the server into a string. You can try this:

```
success: function (result) {
    var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dt.addColumn('string', 'Tasks');
    dt.addColumn('number', 'Count');

    // Taking the "data" property as your controller returns it that way
    var data = result.data;

    $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
        var label = obj[0];
        var value = parseInt(obj[1]);
        dt.addRow([label, value]);
    });

    chartData = dt;
},
```

Comment: fyi: typo at end of this line --> `dt.addRow(label, value);column`

Comment: Still had problem at this line  dt.addRow(label, value);   Changed to dt.addRow([label,value]);

Comment: Yes, I was not familiar with the arguments that the `addRow` function expects. It looks like it must be an array.

Answer (score 0):

**At Controller**

Try this

```
return Json(temp);
```

Comment: Doesn't work json becomes like {"data":[["In Progress","10"]}. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

dt.addRow accept only array or null which that error says

Refere : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#addrow

check below fiddle where i have updated you code.

`check here`http://jsfiddle.net/79ffvayr/109/